# How do I tell if a PictureBox's Image has changed?

Tags: c#, .net, picturebox

Apparently, the PictureBox class does not offer an event when its Image property is set. Is there a way to still catch such a change, possibly by subclassing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could subclass it and [hide the base class' Image property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx), providing your own which raised an event in the property setter ([set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228368.aspx)) if the [value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1khb4f8.aspx) is different.